# Split a string and specify characters like , . :

Tags: javascript, parsing, assembly, split, tokenize

I'm writing an assembler parser using JavaScript (don't ask why)
Need to split words, but characters like `. , :` need to be separate array element

As a solution i can use `.split(' ')` and just check with `.includes(/[,|.|:]/g)` find index and push after that element, but I think there is a better solution for this task.

Example

```
input: 'mov al, bl'
```

```
output: ['mov', 'al', ',', 'bl']
```

Comment: What you're writing right now is a tokenizer, and your current solution sounds much too simplistic. What if the code is `mov al,bl` (no space after the comma)? Or something like `mov eax,[edi + ebx *4]`? I suggest that you search around for information about tokenizers. Perhaps there are libraries written in javascript that can you can leverage.

Comment: If you google a bit, you can find examples how others did it. For example [this browser-based assembly emulator and debugger called Davis](https://github.com/Kobzol/davis) uses [PEG.js](https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs) (a parser generator) with [this grammar file](https://github.com/Kobzol/davis/blob/master/src/app/assembly/asm-parser.peg) to parse x86 assembly. Davis' full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Kobzol/davis) (check the `src/app/assembly` folder).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in `split()` to include separator characters in final array.

```js
let test = "mov al, bl"

let res = test.split(/([,\.:])/).map(el => el.trim().split(" ")).flat()
console.log(res)
```